# Как подключить Json.net

Tags: c#

Собственно, как подключить Json.net в C#.
Пробовал искать в расширениях, но не нашел

Answer (score 7, accepted):

в дополнение к ответу @VladD скажу, что можно (и пожалуй нужно) устанавливать подобные библиотеки через менеджер пакетов Nuget. Если он у вас не установлен, то установите вот так: **Tools => Extensions And Updates**, и в открывшемся окне в окне поиска вбейте **NuGet**. Затем, установив его и перезагрузив Visual Studio, откройте свой проект зайдите в **Project => Manage Nuget Packages**, перейдите на вкладку **Online** и вбейте в строке поиска название нужного пакета (JSON.NET), после чего в результатах поиска получите нужную библиотеку:

[image]

Помимо этого можно установить пакет через консоль. Для этого нужно проделать вот что: 
**Tools => Library Package Manager => Package Manager Connsole** и в появившемся окне вбить **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**.

Comment: А я не нашел.

Comment: +1, не знал, что есть nuget'овский пакет.

Answer (score 4):

Загрузите инсталляцию из https://json.codeplex.com/releases, распакуйте архив, найдите нужные бинарники в каталоге Bin/(ваша версия .NET)/, укажите dll в зависимостях проекта.

Не забудьте включить dll в инсталлятор.